# Best way of preventing access to an action in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, authentication

In an old mvc 1 project I'm adding an option for the users to edit their details. I'm not using Forms Authentication (mainly because I shouldn't change the previous code massively) so I'm trying to think of the best way to only allow the user currently logged to edit his details.

For the moment, given the URL is http://localhost:61681/users/edit?userId=29 other user just have to change the userId to edit others' details.

The way I can just think of is checking inside the method if the userId  matches the parameter, but I don't know if there are better ways to do it.

Let me apologize cause I understand the question shows my very basic knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: How do you currently track the logged-in user?  A session value?

Comment: What is the previous code using for authentication?

Comment: Just cookies for the username (actually the email, which is unique) and the userId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not let the user id you're checking `userId` against, *be* the parameter?  If the edit page isn't meant to let anyone edit anyone else's info, then there's no reason for a `userId` parameter at all -- just let it edit the user that made the request.

Comment: Well, I think I'm not getting you properly. This would mean getting  the current user, via the cookies set currently? and then what kind of check should be made?n

Comment: @mitomed: Just that the user is genuine (ie: that they're actually logged in and not just forging a "this is my user id...honest!" cookie).  If the edit page isn't supposed to edit any other user than the current one, then all you need to do is verify that the current user is valid.  If they are, then show an edit page *for that user id*.  Without a `userId` parameter (other than their own ID), the only user page a user can edit is their own.

Comment: Thanks cHao, problem is that I don't know other way of getting the user than checking the cookies. Which, from what you've just told me is kind of a rubbish thing isn't it?

Comment: @mitomed: In the general case, yes.  Unless you encrypt the cookie or add a hash or HMAC to it, you can't trust that that cookie came from you and not someone tweaking cookies to say they're the site admin or something.  A session cookie would be ok to trust in this way...but not a client-side cookie with the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( currrentUser.Id != userId )
  return Redirect( "http://example.com/access-denied" );
```

If you already know the logged in user then just add a check to see if it matches the id of the user to be edited.If not, don't let them.

Comment: Yep, basically it's what I thought. So you reckon it's the best way